# Is there a package I need to install so atom will recognise my PHP code?

Tags: php, atom-editor

Im learning PHP, but when I type my code into my text editor and use the > symbol, the rest of the code that follows turns grey. Also I cant make a simple echo display in my web browser. Is there something I need to install in my text editor or maybe something else I'm missing? Any suggestions are ideas are appreciated. Thanks

I've tried the same code in Atom and Sublime text 2. Both the same result.

```
<?php
  include_once 'includes/dbh.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo $row['user_uid'];
   }
}
?>
<?php
    $num1 = 8;
    $num2 = 4;
    echo $num1 / $num2;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the web browser to display 'Admin' and a sum result 2. Instead I get the following

```
0) { while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { echo $row['user_uid']; } } ?>
```

Comment: Do you have a webserver and PHP installed ? Do you have error ?

Comment: yeah Xampp and no i dont so thats probably the problem.

Comment: or do you get client side errors ?

Comment: have ayou tried an example that does a single echo ? i mean in your case your even doing a mysqli call which needs an extension

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the package "Language-PHP". Then you can also install atom-autocomplete-php to get the auto-completion. Go to [here](https://atom.io/search?page=2&q=php) to search for different php packages.